# Google script not performing code but no notified error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a budget document if I select "30 days" in column C (C3:C29) than the corresponding amount in column B will be pasted in month column after the month selected in A2.

Like if "January" is present in A2 than when 30 days selected in C3, value of B3 will be copied to the February column in corresponding i.e 3rd row. Similarly if "90 days" is selected C3:C29 any cell than the amount will be divided by 3 and then distributed in the next three months.

Image of output with 30 & 90 days for month of January.
[image]

Here is the code google script

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
    var row = cell.getRow();
    var col = cell.getColumn();

    //if col > A && col < K ...
    if (col > 2 && col < 4 && row > 2 && row < 29) { //C3:
        //do something

        var ss = e.range.getSheet();
        var value1 = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
        var value2 = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
        if (value1 === "January") {
            if (value2 === "30 Days") {

                ss.getRange(row, 5) // "G" is column 7
                    .setValue((ss.getRange(row, 2).getvalue())); //"B" is column 2
            }
            if (value2 === "90 Days") {

                ss.getRange(row, 5) // "G" is column 7
                    .setValue((ss.getRange(row, 2).getvalue()) / 3); //"B" is column 2
                ss.getRange(row, 6) // "G" is column 7
                    .setValue((ss.getRange(row, 2).getvalue()) / 3); //"B" is column 2
                ss.getRange(row, 7) // "G" is column 7
                    .setValue((ss.getRange(row, 2).getvalue()) / 3); //"B" is column 2
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Need to finalize budget any quick help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to fix this using formulas only

Comment: How please explain, because after changing month the previous record will also change

Comment: What is the question? This `col > 2 && col < 4` can be reduced to `col==3`

Comment: Dear you can see above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e)
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = sheet.getSheetName();
 // var row   = range.getRow();
// var col   = range.getColumn(); var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D3:D29");
var value1 = sheet.getRange(29,2).getValue();               //Getting value from B29 in "Raw Data"
    var value2 = sheet.getRange(30,4).getValue();              //Getting value from D30 in "Raw Data"
   var value3 = sheet.getRange(30,5).getValue(); 
  var value4 = sheet.getRange(30,6).getValue(); 
  var value5 = sheet.getRange(30,7).getValue(); 
  var value6 = sheet.getRange(30,8).getValue(); 
  var value7 = sheet.getRange(30,9).getValue(); 
var value8 = sheet.getRange(30,10).getValue(); 
var value9 = sheet.getRange(30,11).getValue(); 
var value10 = sheet.getRange(30,12).getValue();   
var value11 = sheet.getRange(30,13).getValue(); 
  var value12 = sheet.getRange(30,14).getValue(); 
  var value13= sheet.getRange(30,15).getValue(); 

    if(value2>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("D3:D29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("D3:D29").setBackground('purple');
    }


   if(value3>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("E3:E29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("E3:E29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value4>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("F3:F29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("F3:F29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value5>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("G3:G29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("G3:G29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value6>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("H3:H29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("H3:H29").setBackground('purple');
    }

  if(value7>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("I3:I29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("I3:I29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value8>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("J3:J29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("J3:J29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value9>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("K3:K29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("K3:K29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value10>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("L3:L29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("L3:L29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value11>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("M3:M29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("M3:M29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value12>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("N3:N29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("N3:N29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value13>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("O3:O29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("O3:O29").setBackground('purple');
    }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------- 
   var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var value1 = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
        var value2 = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  //if col > A && col < K ...
  if(col > 2 && col < 4 && row > 2 && row < 29){ //C3:
    //do something
 var v = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();

    if (value1==="January") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="February") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="March") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="April") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,8).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="May") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,9).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="June") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="July") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,11).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="August") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,12).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="September") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,13).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="October") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(v);}      }

    if (value1==="November") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,17).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,15).setValue(v);}      }

     if (value1==="December") {if (value2==="90 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,17).setValue(v/3);sheet.getRange(row,18).setValue(v/3);}
                if (value2==="60 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v/2);sheet.getRange(row,17).setValue(v/2);}      
                      if (value2==="30 Days"){sheet.getRange(row,16).setValue(v);}      }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = sheet.getSheetName();
 // var row   = range.getRow();
// var col   = range.getColumn(); var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D3:D29");
var value1 = sheet.getRange(29,2).getValue();               //Getting value from B29 in "Raw Data"
    var value2 = sheet.getRange(30,4).getValue();              //Getting value from D30 in "Raw Data"
   var value3 = sheet.getRange(30,5).getValue(); 
  var value4 = sheet.getRange(30,6).getValue(); 
  var value5 = sheet.getRange(30,7).getValue(); 
  var value6 = sheet.getRange(30,8).getValue(); 
  var value7 = sheet.getRange(30,9).getValue(); 
var value8 = sheet.getRange(30,10).getValue(); 
var value9 = sheet.getRange(30,11).getValue(); 
var value10 = sheet.getRange(30,12).getValue();   
var value11 = sheet.getRange(30,13).getValue(); 
  var value12 = sheet.getRange(30,14).getValue(); 
  var value13= sheet.getRange(30,15).getValue(); 

    if(value2>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("D3:D29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("D3:D29").setBackground('purple');
    }


   if(value3>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("E3:E29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("E3:E29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value4>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("F3:F29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("F3:F29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value5>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("G3:G29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("G3:G29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value6>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("H3:H29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("H3:H29").setBackground('purple');
    }

  if(value7>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("I3:I29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("I3:I29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value8>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("J3:J29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("J3:J29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value9>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("K3:K29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("K3:K29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value10>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("L3:L29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("L3:L29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value11>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("M3:M29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("M3:M29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value12>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("N3:N29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("N3:N29").setBackground('purple');
    }

   if(value13>value1)
    {
      sheet.getRange("O3:O29").setBackground('red');
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.getRange("O3:O29").setBackground('purple');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A few issues:

1. you are using strict comparison ("===") in your if statements so your value as well as type have to be equal. In your case you would have to explicitly cast the value of cell in `col==3` to a string using `toString()` or simply use ("==").
2. `value1` in your code is probably undefined since, "sheets" is not defined in your code.
3. "getvalue" is not a function, `getValue()` is.
4. assuming "sheet" is replaced by "ss" then `value2` would still return a number (amount) and not a "30 day or 90 day" string.

If you fix all of that, then the script will work. Also, you might find using `console.log()` useful for debugging issues.

### Example:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  console.log(cell);
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  if (col == 3 && row > 2 && row < 29) { //C3:  
    var ss = e.range.getSheet();
    var value1 = ss.getRange(2, 1).getValue().toString();
    var value2 = ss.getRange(row, 3).getValue().toString();
    if (value1 === "January") {
      if (value2 === "30 Days") {
        ss.getRange(row, 5) // "G" is column 7
        .setValue((ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue())); //"B" is column 2
      }
      else if (value2 === "90 Days") {
        var value = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue() / 3;
        ss.getRange(row, 5) 
        .setValue(value); 
        ss.getRange(row, 6) 
        .setValue(value); 
        ss.getRange(row, 7) 
        .setValue(value); 
      }

    }
  }
}
```